Nextflow: mkdir: cannot create directory 'filename': File exists
I'm trying to setup a workflow using Nextflow on WSL2. After some changes, here is the full updated code:
params.output_dir = "./workflow_output"
params.input_dir = null

process fastQC {
    publishDir(
        path: "$params.output_dir/qc_reports",
        mode: "copy"
    )

    input:
    val fqs

    output:
    path "$params.input_dir/*_fastqc.zip", emit: zip
    path "$params.input_dir/*_fastqc.html", emit: html

    """
    fastqc $fqs
    """
}

workflow onlyQC {
    out_dir = file("$params.output_dir")
    fqs = channel.from(file("$params.input_dir/*.fastq"))
    
    fastQC(fqs) 
}

Before changing the fastqc process to use publishDir, I was receiving the following error message when I attempted to use mkdir -p $out_dir prior to running the fastqc -o $out_dir $fqs command.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘workflow_output’: File exists
I changed to the updated code by using the publishDir directive, but now I get the error:
Missing output file(s) data/*_fastqc.zip expected by process onlyQC:fastQC (3)
Any guidance/help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Side note, there's no sense in mkdir -p this ; mkdir -p this/that. The whole point of mkdir -p is that it creates nonexistent parents, so just the second one is enough to do the job.

@hobbs did not realize this, thanks!


mkdir: cannot create directory ‘workflow_output’: File exists

You get this error because you are asking Nextflow to stage the output directory (i.e. out_dir) into the process working directory (under ./work), and, by default, input files and directories will be symbolic linked (this can be changed using the stageInMode directive). Note that mkdir will not follow the symlink but instead interpret it as a file, hence the error.
A better way to publish process outputs is to use the publishDir directive. For example:
params.fastqs = "/path/to/*.fastq"
params.output_dir = "./workflow_output"


process fastQC {

    publishDir(
        path: "${params.output_dir}/fastQC",
        mode: 'copy',
    )

    input:
    path fqs

    output:
    path "*_fastqc.zip", emit: zip
    path "*_fastqc.html", emit: html

    """
    fastqc ${fqs}
    """
}

workflow {

    fastqs = Channel.fromPath("${params.fastqs}")

    fastQC( fastqs )
}


Thanks for the help!
When I attempt to follow the solutions you gave, I'm getting an error message:
Missing output file(s) data/*_fastqc.zip expected by process onlyQC:fastQC (3).
I manually verified that the files are indeed being generated in the data/ folder, so I'm unsure why Nextflow isn't finding them.

@MananChopra How are you running FastQC exactly? For the files to be generated in a subdirectory called data, I'd expect your script block to look something like mkdir data; fastqc -o data ${fqs}.

The input files are located in the data/ dir, so without the -o flag specified FastQC will output to that same dir by default. I guess my code should really read ${input_dir}/*_fastqc.zip since it will not always be named data, but that is not affecting this test case. Im not sure why nextflow isn't finding the files, since I manually checked and they are indeed being generated in the data/ directory.

@MananChopra But when the above process is run, input: path fqs will ensure that each fastq file is localized into its own process working directory (e.g. ./work/01/<uuid>) by way of a symbolic link. Then when fastqc is executed (without -o), the zip and html outputs should also be created alongside the localized fastq file (i.e. the symlink). This is what lets us simply use output: path "*_fastqc.html" to tell Nextflow what html files to expect. Make sure to use input type path to stage the fastq files. Using input: val fqs is a mistake if that is what you have in your code.

Please edit your question to show the updated code you're using if I've misunderstood what the problem is, thanks!

Thanks for all your help @Steve. I've updated the main question with the new code. I think my problems are happening because of a few misunderstandings on my part on how Nextflow works. I changed val fqs to be path fqs and removed data from the output lines and the process now runs as expected.
Do you have any recommendations as far as resources to get a more solid understanding of Nextflow? I've just been combing through the docs which I feel are a little lacking at times, though that could definitely just be a me problem :)

@MananChopra You are not alone with that opinion. A good place to start now is https://training.nextflow.io/. Also, the section in the docs about multiple input channels should also be mandatory reading but is easily missed.
